# ImportError: cannot import name 'validate' from jsonschema

Tags: python, jsonschema

I'm quite new in python and faced this issue after the manual installation of the new `jsonschema` dependency.

```
$ python /var/www/html/graylog.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/graylog.py", line 18, in <module>
    from jsonschema import validate
ImportError: cannot import name 'validate'
```

Python version `3.6.8`

This is the current `pip list`

```
Package            Version
------------------ --------
attrs              19.3.0
certifi            2019.3.9
chardet            3.0.4
Click              7.0
configparser       5.0.0
Flask              1.0.2
Flask-WTF          0.14.2
grapi              0.1.4
idna               2.8
importlib-metadata 1.6.1
itsdangerous       1.1.0
Jinja2             2.10
jsonschema         3.2.0
M2Crypto           0.35.2
MarkupSafe         1.1.1
Nuitka             0.6.8.3
pip                20.1.1
prometheus-client  0.8.0
PyMySQL            0.9.3
pyrsistent         0.16.0
PySimpleGUI        3.29.0
requests           2.21.0
setuptools         39.2.0
six                1.15.0
urllib3            1.24.1
virtualenv         16.4.3
Werkzeug           0.15.1
WTForms            2.2.1
zipp               3.1.0
```

Comment: are you sure you're invoking the correct python? do you have only one python installed in your system? have you tried with `python3` and `pip3`?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? If not do update your question with your running environemnt

Answer (score 6):

Try to update the `jsonSchema` version that often solves the error especially if it's been installed manually

```
pip install --upgrade jsonschema
```

It may also be that the `python` that you are using in your environment may point to a different version that does not contain the `jsonSchema` module. Try

```
python3 /var/www/html/graylog.py
```

Comment: this helped me to build QMK Firmaware